# Workbook open event not firing when opening file from SharePoint on Excel 2010

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, com, excel-2010

So I got this problem with Excel, that seems to be specific to Excel 2010 only. When I run the file from SharePoint location, no workbook open event fires.

It's an Excel COM add-in and we use `Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler`, that's not being fired when the sheet is opened as it should be.

Is this a known issue and is there any way to work around it?

EDIT:

OK guys, as I stated somewhere in comments, I originally intended only to learn if this is a known issue and what options I had, but since there was a lot of negative feedback for a perfectly legit, short and to the point question, I will now provide all the info requested including my newest findings.

It is not a VSTO add-in, this is a COM add in, and yeah, I have eyes to see if the sheet has been opened in safe mode.

So, I created a small-scale add-in quickly to prove the point, registered it in my registry and tested the `OnConnection` method when I ran the workbook from my machine. However, when I ran it from the SharePoint server, even `OnConnection` method didn't get called.

Now our original add-in did get loaded, as it is a 2 part component, which is why I thought just the `WorkbookOpen` event didn't fire, but it turns out the Excel 2010 is run in some mode that prevents add-ins from running on start-up. Hopefully this clears things up a bit and maybe some of you will have another idea or two.

EDIT 2:

I just realized there was this one guy who downloaded sheet from the internet and thought he was replicating the issue. I was running it from SharePoint, meaning I opened it from its SharePoint location, but easiest way to replicate is this:
[image]

Comment: I just tested this and couldn't reproduce your issue. The `Workbook_Open` event worked as expected when opening from Sharepoint using Excel 2010.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, this is not about Workbook_Open macro, it's about `Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler`. We have a C# add-in for Excel.

Comment: This is indeed quite unclear and confusing. Please put question clarifications in the question itself, not in comments. Your question can be edited by clicking the "edit" link.

Comment: Sure, I know how to edit my question, but I honestly don't expect anyone to solve the problem. It was intended for someone to tell me if this is a known issue, and I guess it's not, I might file a bug report to Microsoft...

Comment: errr, you don't expect anyone to come up with a solution? then why did you even ask the question?

Comment: Please see edited response, you caught me a second after I accidentally submitted.

Comment: Can you upload that small-scale example of the code you have that doesn't work (temp-share). I've made Excel COM add-ins in the past with AddIn Express and the workbook_open events do fire from SPS. Can you also show what trust center settings you have.

Comment: Dude, just right click on your Excel 2010 pinned on your taskbar and open the workbook from SharePoint, your add-in won't load. I just implement `IDTExtensibility2` and OnConnection doesn't get called.

Comment: Are you referring to *me* as that guy **your spending last few days teaching how to run Workbooks from SharePoint, how to create COM add-ins**?? I cant see who else you're referring too? Did they delete their comments or something? Either way its a poor attitude to slag someone off here on Stackoverflow. I cant believe you are wanting help but not prepared to provide a sample to reproduce the issue... none of us can reproduce it and I think Microsoft would have heard if COM Addins didn't work on spreadsheets stored in SPS retieived via a VPP

Comment: I was referring to you. You were the one who downloaded the sheet using browser and then ran it from your hard drive, and you were the one who just clicks wizards to create add-ins? So let's get this straight now, you created the add in that implements IDTExtensibility2, and then properly ran your sheet from remote location and you were not able to replicate the issue? Or you were frustrated with my observations and didn't give it another try? I think no one here tried to reproduce it, but I give you that you are persistent. Let's reproduce it, you write an answer and I accept it.

Comment: I tried it on multiple machines, it happens on all of them. It's a bug or a "feature" that got corrected in Excel 2013. I wanted to know if it was known, but now I just have to prove I'm not mad, since you keep saying I don't help you even though I reply to every question and guide you to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you convert your COM Add-in to [a VSTO Add-In to future proof it](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/11/16/installations-of-office-2013-may-not-allow-com-add-ins-to-register-successfully.aspx). I know this is Office2010 specific though from Office2013 onwards COM Add-Ins are not [fully supported](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2792179) - *irrespective of Sharepoint*.

---

**Ignore below, its an old part of answer before context of problem was provided....**

> My AddIns Workbook open event is not firing when opening file
>   from SharePoint on Excel 2010, is this a known issue and is there any
>   way to work around it?

Something odd is going on in your environment or configuration because I cannot reproduce the issue using Excel 2010. Here is my VSTO AddIn code:

```
namespace ExcelAddIn1OpenEventFromSharepoint
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.WorkbookOpen +=new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpen);
        }

        private void Application_WorkbookOpen(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wb)
        {
            if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Final)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This is a readonly workbook");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This is read/write workbook");
            }
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
         //[VSTO Generated Code]
    }
}
```

When I open a workbook from our SPS site, I see the messagebox:

[image]

Please try this same vanilla bare bones code and if the workbook open event still doesn't fire then check your **Trust Center** settings:

[image]

Go through all the settings:

1. Trusted Locations
2. Trusted Documents
3. AddIns
4. File Blocking
5. Privacy Options

Comment: This is not a VSTO add in.

Comment: Huh: *Sorry if I wasn't clear, this is not about Workbook_Open macro, it's about `Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler`. We have a C# add-in for Excel.* - it is VSTO

Comment: Or is it a COM Addin?

Comment: It's COM visible add in. It is not VSTO.

Comment: So is there anything else you can share that will help us to help you? Like did you try the Trust Center settings? Show us what settings you have with screenshots? You're not making it easy

Comment: Does the code I posted "thinking it was VSTO" work? What OS are you using and the server too, plus version of SPS? Show us the code you have that doesn't work? Have you taken any Procmon or Netmon/Wireshark traces? Did this work at any point, is it intermittent, or it's never worked? Has there been any config or environment changes recently? What have you tried? What led you to say "you didn't think anyone could fix it just posting to see if anyone else has experienced this/known issue?"

Comment: I've posted a lot of additional info to original question. I use Win7 64bit Office 2010 32bit the sheet get's loaded fine, so I didn't try tracing, and I don't believe it will help. it's probably hard-coded into Excel on how to run the workbook from network location. It never worked and it doesn't work on both our customer's machine or mine, so it's pretty easy to replicate. I said that because I think it's problem in Excel, so no one will know or it will turn out to be a bug.

Comment: Yeah, but we had multiple reasons to go for COM add-in, and we have no issues on 2013, so we're fine for now. I'm guessing you managed to repeat the issue, and probably it happens with VSTOs too. I leave it here for a few days and hopefully we can conclude it's some strange kind of bug or a try at security by Microsoft.

Comment: I worked for MS in ProDev and suggest you raise a support ticket with them. They will need the bare-bones repro. I couldn't repro it with VSTO (it works as per the earlier part of my anwser) and I did open the spreadsheet from a URL (I did try both ways). I had other issues repro it with a COM AddIn implementing IDTExtensibility2 - I am in a completely locked down environment (bank) so couldn't troubleshoot it with admin. Hope you find an answer or take it up with Microsoft. My gut feeling is they will point you to "Office 365" or at least VSTO as an answer as they are phasing COM-AddIns out.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the Workbook was open in the Protected View. In that case you will not get the WorkbookOpen event fired. Try to handle the [ProtectedViewWindowOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194431(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired when a workbook is opened in a Protected View window.

Here is what MSDN states for the ProtectedView object:

A Protected View window is used to display a workbook from a potentially unsafe location. Unsafe locations are defined as the following:

- Files opened from the Internet.
  Attachments opened from Microsoft Outlook 2010.
- Files blocked by File Block Policy.
- Files that fail Office File Validation.
- Files explicitly opened in Protected View by using the Open in Protected View command of the Open button in the Open dialog box.

Workbooks displayed in a Protected View window cannot be edited and are restricted from running active content such as Visual Basic for Applications macros and data connections. For more information about Protected View windows, see [What is Protected View?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/what-is-protected-view-HA010355931.aspx?CTT=1).

To return a single ProtectedViewWindow object from the ProtectedViewWindows collection, use ProtectedViewWindows(Index), where Index is the index number of the window you want to open. You can also access the ProtectedViewWindow object that represents the active Protected View window by using the [ActiveProtectedViewWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195068.aspx) property of the Application object.

After you access a ProtectedViewWindow object, use the [Workbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196579.aspx) property to access the Workbook object that represents the workbook file that is open in the Protected View window. Because a Protected View window is designed to protect the user from potentially malicious code, the operations you can perform by using a Workbook object returned by a ProtectedViewWindow object will be limited. Operations that are not allowed will return an error.

Comment: I will need some time to check this out, but doesn't protected workbook scream it's protected?

Comment: No, only the line under the ribbon is displayed to the user asking to switch to the normal view. See [What is Protected View?](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653).